# CCS PIC18f252 UART module remapped

Tags: uart, pic

I took off a project involving a PIC18F252. The code is compiled with CCS and I am just migrating it to MPLAB.
The PIC has 1 UART module, its TX and RX pins are RC6 and RC7. I am not a microchip expert but I have worked a bit on them, and have looked online before posting this question.

The original code is using

```
#use rs232(baud=9600,xmit=PIN_B5,rcv=PIN_B4,restart_wdt)
```

As far as I can see, the PIC doesn't permit remapping.
So how is that possible?
What is CCS doing "under the hood"?
So the UART pins are RB4 and RB5?

Comment: CCS uses its own library to setup the UART using #use rs232(baud=9600,xmit=PIN_B5,rcv=PIN_B4,restart_wdt). These are the CCS IDE specific definition which can't be found exactly the same in the others. In MPLAB you have to do it all because MPLAB has no libraries. It has a tool called MPLAB Code Configurator (MCC) which provides an interface to simplify chip and peripheral setup and generate peripheral driver code. But unfortunately it doesn't support the PIC18F252 since it is an old chip. Conclusion, you have to write the UART driver code from scratch.

Comment: Thank you! I think I better just upgrade the pic. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use more recent products like PIC18(L)FxxKxx or PIC18(L)FxxJxx or PIC18(L)FxxQxx. They are improved and supported by MCC.

Comment: OK thanks, by the way I do not find the flag to set this thread as "solved"...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
#use rs232(baud=9600,xmit=PIN_B5,rcv=PIN_B4,restart_wdt)
```

is an extension of the CCS compiler to write some configuration data into the configuration register of the UART module (e.g. baudrate) and can't be used with the xc8 compiler. Have a look into your datasheet how to setup the UART module.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. 
Yes I got that, but what I wanted to know was what CCS does in its library to be able to use different pins than the MSSP dedicated ones. As Kozmotronik mentioned, I think CCS just does what a UART driver would do, but using any pins (toggling pins and bits sequentially, etc.). So if I wanted to use a similar lib in xc8 I would have to write a driver that can take any pins, and make them act like TX/RX, which is a pain. So in my case, upgrading the PIC is a much easier and durable solution.

Comment: If CCS uses different pins than mentioned in the datasheet (RC4 and RC5) , they will use a software UART and not the module included in the controller.